# Display content of uploaded PDF document by user using file Reader

Tags: javascript, node.js, filereader

I am trying to display content of a pdf file uploaded by the user using FileReader but i am getting random characters instead, however i have tried reading uploaded text file (.txt) and its working fine.

**Edit**:
Some people have suggested to use iframe to display the pdf content but i am not sure how to set the src="" attribute to be the uploaded file src url

this is how i used the iframe:

```
 <iframe  id="frame" src="this should be the src of user input pdf file" style="width: 100%; height: 600px; border: none;"></iframe>
```

this is the html where the user choose the file:

```
<b-form-file   input="file"  class="mb-2 m-2" @change="uploadFile"/>
```

file variable:

```
data(){
      return {

        file: null,
}
}
```

uploadFile handler:

```
async uploadFile(ev){


           this.file=ev;
}
```

Another button to display the content:

```
<b-button class="ml-2"@click="displayArticle">Display Article</b-button>
```

displayArticle handler:

```
 displayArticle(){

           const reader= new FileReader()


           reader.onload=  function(){




             this.content=reader.result.toString();
             document.getElementById("fileContents").textContent=this.content;



//this will display the
 //content of the file in 
//fileContents div if its .txt file,
 //however i want to set the src attribute of 
//iframe to be the source of 
//the uploaded file from the user 
//to be able to display the pdf file
//by something like this:

             document.getElementById("frame").src=" source of uploaded file "




           }





           reader.readAsText(this.file.target.files[0]);



        }
```

```
<pre id="fileContents" style=" font-size: medium; font-weight: bold; padding: 5px ">  </pre>
```

Comment: Need to embed a pdf in html and browser will use default pdf reader to render it

Answer (score 0):

Your filereader is not caring about the correct format for your text, instead it just displays the raw contents of what makes up that file.
You may want to embed your file in your page as one comment suggests,
or you may want to change the format of the text rendered to the page. Either way you should use the built in tools to display pdfs... this may help you:

```
<iframe src="pdf-link"></iframe>
```

EDIT : save the url of the pdf that the user uploads to a database; then display the pdf by retrieving the url from your database.

Comment: hi, i tried using iframe and it worked but with src="link of pdf from internet", i want to put the src to be the file uploaded by the user (from his computer), any help with that?

Comment: youre going to need something like php to handle file uploading, a database to store the link-to-the-new-pdf address of the file upload and code to retreive the link address and display it in the iframe. if ive helped you please give me a upvote as your question is way too vague. youre basically asking us for code but your not showing us any code, framework, anything youve used up till now to attempt... so it will be very hard to answer the question in its current form.

Comment: can you please check my updated post, i will be grateful. Thanks in advance

Comment: i am not sure how to get the url of the uploaded document.. i have tried this and it doesnt work:               document.getElementById("frame").src=this.file.target.files[0].url;

Comment: thanks! i retrieved the url using: var url = URL.createObjectURL(ev.target.files[0]);
           var preview=document.getElementById("frame");
           preview.setAttribute('src', url); and it works fine now

Comment: upvote and/or accept my answer please if it was useful